# arrays and mysqli insert

Tags: arrays, mysqli, insert

once again thanks for your help in advance im looking to pre fill a mysqli insert statement with data filled from an array and cannot seem to get it to work it just doesnt insert and im kinda stuck and looking for ideas

this is what im chasing as a end result as for code but cannot seem to get it to work

```
$table_colums= array("db_colum1","db_colum2");
$forms_data = array("form_data1","form_data2");

$sql = INSERT into some_table ($table_colums) VALUES ($forms_data)
```

obviously if i do it the old fashion way it will work but i need to have it get its values from the arrays because there dynamic and filled from a database

```
$sql = INSERT into some_table (db_colum1,db_colum2) VALUES ('form_data1','form_data2')
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you a library I wrote, [SafeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql), which is doing exactly what you want - adding arrays to mysql (among many other wonderful things).

Though you need another kind of array, but I suppose it would be even simpler:

```
include 'safemysql.class.php';
$db = new safemysql();

$data = array(
  "db_colum1" => "form_data1",
  "db_colum2" => "form_data2",
);
$db->query("INSERT INTO some_table SET ?u", $data);
```

Nothing could be easier.